# Accessing the same file between two different WSL2 installations in Windows?

Tags: linux, samba, wsl2

I have two WSL2 installations, but I have a need to access/modify the same file on both of them.

My first thought would be that maybe I need to set up a samba share between the two of them; but I'm not sure which one is which ip on the interfaces in Windows.

Each installation is on a separate user account.

Is there an easier way to do this?

NOTE: This was also asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768936/accessing-the-same-file-between-two-different-wsl2-installations-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment1467931_768936).

Comment: For an installation like this, trying to change one file by two users will likely damage the file (OS may be confused) .  Change sequentially

Comment: Move the file to the Windows side. Both instances will be able to access the file. Obviously not at the same time.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah that sounds correct.  Thank you Ramhound.